# Issues with Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server-2012, log-shipping

First time at posting a question on here, so please bear with me and I'll try and detail all the information.

Currently, I'm log shipping from SQL 2012 Standard Edition (11.0.3000) (lets call it ServerA) to another server in a  data centre in a different domain (ServerDR) which is also SQL 2012 Standard Edition (11.0.3128). This log shipping is working fine and is reporting fine on the history.

When I then log ship from ServerA to another server (we'll call this ServerB) within the same network / domain I run into some issues. This is also SQL 2012 Standard Edition (11.0.3000), but ServerB is also used for Reporting duties. These only one of these databases will be reported against, the others are purely for a warm backup.

There is 7 databases being logshipped from ServerA to ServerDR and the same 7 databases are being logshipped from ServerA to ServerB. When logshipping from ServerA to ServerB, 6 of those databases will have issues when trying to restore the transaction log backup's, leaving the databases on ServerB in a restoring state, when I have set this to be left in standby / Read only mode.

Looking through the logs, this will happen. First part is the successful restore of the log, then the next will error:

**2013-12-27 15:16:03.49    Restored log backup file. Secondary DB: 'Logship_xxxxx', File: 'F:\Logshipped Files\xxxxx_20131224171511.trn'**

> 2013-12-27 15:16:05.82    *** Error: Could not apply log backup file 'F:\Logshipped Files\xxxxx_20131224171511.trn' to secondary database 'Logship_xxxxx'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: An error occurred while processing the log for database 'Logship_xxxxx'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.
>   An error occurred during recovery, preventing the database 'Logship_xxxxx' (27:0) from restarting. Diagnose the recovery errors and fix them, or restore from a known good backup. If errors are not corrected or expected, contact Technical Support.
>   RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.
>   Processed 0 pages for database 'Logship_xxxxx', file 'xxxxx' on file 1.
>   Processed 1 pages for database 'Logship_xxxxx', file 'xxxxx' on file 1.(.Net SqlClient Data Provider)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82  Skipping log backup file 'F:\Logshipped Files\xxxxx_20131224173011.trn' for secondary database 'Logship_xxxxx' because the file could not be verified.
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: Could not apply log backup file 'F:\Logshipped Files\xxxxx_20131224174511.trn' to secondary database 'Logship_xxxxx'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82  Skipping log backup file 'F:\Logshipped Files\xxxxx_20131224174511.trn' for secondary database 'Logship_xxxxx' because the file could not be verified.
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: Could not apply log backup file 'F:\Logshipped Files\xxxxx_20131224180010.trn' to secondary database 'Logship_xxxxx'.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.(System.Data)** 
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82  Skipping log backup file 'F:\Logshipped Files\xxxxx_20131224180010.trn' for secondary database 'Logship_xxxxx' because the file could not be verified.
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82   **Error: Could not log history/error message.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.LogShipping) ***
>   2013-12-27 15:16:05.82  *** Error: ExecuteNon

My thinking is, there is no issue with the transaction log backups, otherwise ServerDR would be suffering with the same issues. I have re-created the log ship jobs and restored a known good backup on ServerB, but it will break again.

One thing I have noticed though, is if I manually (and painfully) restore each transaction log backup, it still throws errors when using this T-SQL:

```
RESTORE LOG Logship_xxxxx
FROM DISK='F:\Logshipped Files\xxxxx_20131224164516.trn'
WITH STANDBY='F:\Logshipped Files\UNDO\UNDO_xxxxx_ARCHIVE.DAT'
```

Which will give an error of:

> Processed 0 pages for database 'Logship_xxxxx', file 'xxxxx' on file 1.
>   Processed 1 pages for database 'Logship_xxxxx', file 'xxxxx_log' on file 1.
>   Msg 9004, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
>   An error occurred while processing the log for database 'Logship_xxxxx'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.
>   Msg 3414, Level 21, State 1, Line 1
>   An error occurred during recovery, preventing the database 'Logship_xxxxx' (27:0) from restarting. Diagnose the recovery errors and fix them, or restore from a known good backup. If errors are not corrected or expected, contact Technical Support.

But, if I keep working through each transaction log, sometimes I'll get:

> Processed 0 pages for database 'Logship_xxxxx', file 'xxxxx' on file 1.
>   Processed 1 pages for database 'Logship_xxxxx', file 'xxxxx_log' on file 1.
>   RESTORE LOG successfully processed 1 pages in 0.042 seconds (0.034 MB/sec).

This will put the database back into standby mode, for it to only break again :-( I have also noticed that it doesn't break on the log shipping, when the transaction log files are larger than 10kb or so in size.

Any ideas on this one at all? Apologies for the long post and the somewhat iffy formatting.

Comment: What happens if you run `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` against the problematic log backup file?  It sounds like that particular log backup file is corrupt.

Comment: But if that log file was corrupt, surely ServerDR would suffer the same fate? It's the same log file that is being shipped to ServerDR as it is to ServerB.

Comment: Just to add to that, I have tried RESTORE VERIFYONLY on a bunch of the transaction logs and they all return 'The backup set on file 1 is valid'

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with one log file, or am I misunderstanding?  What if you try the command on that log file.  Additionally, each log shipping job will copy the files to its own directory.  As such, the file copied for ServerB might have been corrupted where the ServerDR was copied fine.

Comment: Hi Mike, it's not just the one log file that is the issue. I have checked the file size between ServerB and ServerDR and they are both the same. I have also ran a command fn_dump_dblog and compared the 2 files on both servers and they are the same. I also noticed there was a similar questions asked on here a while back with the same issue [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36135/log-shipping-restore-with-standby-on-sql-server-2012-keeps-breaking). I appreciate the help you are giving, fresh set of eyes makes a big difference.

Comment: Msg 9004, Level 16, State 6, Line 1 An error occurred while processing the log for database, implies that not your log backups but your log file itself of database logship_xxx on serverB gets corrupted while the restore is writing to it. Did you check that everything is correctly configured regarding IO subsystem or if there are any related errors on ServerB?

Comment: Offtopic: Please update your server with version 11.0.3000 (sp1) to any CU or apply the mandatory hotfix. further details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2674319/en-us

Comment: Hi Edward. I have applied that updated you linked to, thanks. The IO is fine, as there are other various LDF files kept on the same drive volume, so surely this would show up for all DB's? I did have a look at any event logs and everything seems to be okay. I deleted the logshipped DB and setup log shipping again, this worked fine during production hours and then failed at around 18:45 which is when the DB isn't used anymore. My thinking is, if there isn't any data change, log shipping fails, which it shouldn't do.

Comment: Just to add another comment to this. I setup log shipping to another server within the domain (ServerC) and this has worked successfully, whilst it broke again on ServerB. The only difference between these 2 servers, is ServerB also runs Reporting Services, whereas ServerC and ServerDR doesn't.

Comment: Can you check windows event logs for any corruption ?

Comment: facing the same issue. Log shipping has been 100% reliable until we upgraded to sql 2012 but since we've been getting corrupted trn files at random, breaking the chain every so often. Its a real pita

Comment: I have the same issue with SQL Server 2017 - but it only happens every once in a while. Did we ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but I did seem to find something on here, that it was down to the disk allocation size being 4k whereas the other disk was a different size, but was rectified in a CU update from MS

Answer (score -3):

I am currently facing the same issue.

If you keep the restoration mode to `NO RECOVERY`, this should solve the issue.

If you change the restoration mode back to `STANDBY` you will start getting the same error again.